# PayPal: Where to start for online payment?

Tags: paypal

I have a single wordpress plugin in my site, that in general is free. But I have create a backlink at the end of my plugin for my site.

What I like to do, is to allow the plugin users to remove the backlink but with a litle payment like ie. $5,00.

The backlink removal will be done with a serial number I will generate for each customer automaticly after the payment.

My general problem is not how to create the serial, or how to validate the serial number and thinks like that.

What I want is to show me any good resource (ie: Tutorials) to read for PayPal payments. if any :)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy. First, you need a paypal account. Then, your first choice is the [developer site of paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/). Paypal has great documentation for the multitude of APIs they offer. Most of the documentation can be found [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation). Especially the Paypal-NVP-API is very easy to implement, and for testing purposes you can use their sandbox.